# problem copying attributes from the same table

Tags: python, odoo

I want to copy one attribute to another when some restrictions pass. So the restrictions are that if the entry amount is greater than 0 than the entry $ is the same as the exit $. For this I have the following code that executes me without errors but the attributes are not copied.

```
  @ api.multi
  @ api.onchange ("total_debit", "total_credit")
  def _copyatribute (self):
      for rec in self:
        if rec.quantity_input > 0:
            rec.total_debit = rec.total_credit
```

That may be wrong so it doesn't copy. It is worth mentioning that the total_debit and total_credit field is computed

Answer (score 1):

IMO copy will not work if `total_debit` is a function field. Because at the end, it will execute it's own compute function. Exception `store=True`

You may extend logic of `total_debit` field to assign your desire values.

Comment: could you give me some example of what you say in You may extend logic of total_debit field to assign your desire values. please